# pulse width using pic 18f4550

Tags: c, microcontroller, pic, microchip, pulse

I want to measure  pulse duration using only one CCP model in capture mode with a pic 18f4550, so I try to detect the rising edge in first time, when a rising edge is detected the timer1 turn on and  the capture mode change to falling edge, with this method I have to measure the pulse width, but the code I use doesn't work well!!
it was good when I used two CCP model.
if anyone could help, I will be grateful.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "osc_config.h"
#include "LCD_8bit_file.h"
#include <string.h>



void main()
{
    unsigned long comtage;
    unsigned long DEPHASAGE[20];
    float Deph_tempo;
    
    TRISCbits.TRISC2=1;
   
    
    IRCF0=1;     
    IRCF1=1;
    IRCF2=1;  
    
    LCD_Init();
    
    LCD_String_xy(0,0,"Deph.tempo"); 
 
    PIE1bits.CCP1IE=1;
    PIR1bits.CCP1IF=0; 
    
    
    CCP1CON=0b00000101; 
    CCPR1=0;        
    
    T1CONbits.RD16=1;
    T1CKPS0=0;
    T1CKPS1=0;
    TMR1CS=0;
    
    TMR1IF=0; 
    TMR1=0; 
        
        
    while(1)        
    {    
        
     
       if(PIR1bits.CCP1IF==1){ 
        
        TMR1ON=1; 
        PIR1bits.CCP1IF=0;
        
        CCP1CON=0b00000100;
        
        while(!(PIR1bits.CCP1IF==1)) 
            
         comtage= TMR1; 
         PIR1bits.CCP1IF=0;
         
           Deph_tempo = (((float)comtage /30.518)/65536 ); 
            sprintf(DEPHASAGE,"%.5f  ",Deph_tempo); 

            LCD_String_xy(2,0,DEPHASAGE);
            
       }
         
        TMR1=0;
        TMR1ON=0; 
        CCP1CON=0b00000101;
    }                              
}
```

Comment: Were you using floating point in the previous code? My (not very recent) experience of the PIC manufacturer's floating point library was it was so slow as to be unusable. I see you aren't using interrupts to do the timer capture.

Comment: What does "doesn't work well" mean? Not working at all, inaccurate results, wildly wrong results...? I see the target of your `sprintf` isn't a byte array but `unsigned long DEPHASAGE[20];` How does that affect things?

Comment: yes I have already used the floating point in my previous code, for the interrupts I don't use them because I work with pulses of 0.001s max.

Comment: the code I used works with inaccurate results.

Comment: For embedded R/T [especially with underpowered CPUs], I've used "scaled" integer arithmetic instead of floating point. Dividing by 65536 is just right shifting by 16. So, you may be able to use (e.g): `unsigned long tempo; tempo = comtage; tempo *= 1000; tempo /= 30518; tempo >>= 16;` with adjustments to `sprintf`.

Comment: Also, is this your real code? You have: `while(!(PIR1bits.CCP1IF==1))` and then: `comtage= TMR1;`. But, I _think_ you're missing a `;` because this is: `while(!(PIR1bits.CCP1IF==1)) comtage = TMR1;` Probably okay, but I think you meant: `while(!(PIR1bits.CCP1IF==1));` Also, after the `while`, I think `PIR1bits.CCP1IF=0;` is extraneous because the bit is already 0. Is it valid [on this arch] to _write_ to a [status?] bit that may be R/O. Sometimes, this can produce unexpected results (e.g. missed interrupts, etc.) Either the bit clears eventually or you have to clear it but [usually] not both

Comment: this is my real code, and even when I add a ; after  while (! (PIR1bits.CCP1IF == 1)) the result  still the same.
I added PIR1bits.CCP1IF == 0 after the while when the code gives inaccurate results cause I thought this will produce a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reducing the number of instructions being exceuted while waiting for CCP1IF will  increase precision.  Have you tried this?

```
// ...

while (1)        
{    
    CCP1CON         = 0b00000101;
    PIR1bits.CCP1IF = 0;
    TMR1ON          = 0; 
    TMR1            = 0;

    // if your comms with the LCD use interrupts:
    //
    // disable interrupts here 

    while (!PIR1bits.CCP1IF)
        ;

    TMR1ON          = 1; 
    CCP1CON         = 0b00000100;
    PIR1bits.CCP1IF = 0;
    
    while (!PIR1bits.CCP1IF)
       ; 

    compte = TMR1; 
    
    // if your comms with the LCD use interrupts:
    //
    // enable interrupts here 

    // refresh display

    // if your comms with the LCD use interrupts:
    //
    // you may want to add a small delay here, to
    // allow for comms to the LCD to end.
    // this may not be necessary, depending on the
    // signal frequency. 
}

// ...
```

If that doesn't work, you should check that the LCD is NOT using interruots.

If it does, you should:

- disable interrupts before reading a sample
- keep interrupts disabled while timing
- enable interrupts before updating the display
- add a delay before taking the next sample, the delay should be long enough for the LCD buffer to empty.

That's for a solution without using interrupts... I think you'll get better results using pin change interrupts and a free running timer.

EDIT: After writing this solution, I found the bug in your code, around these lines of code:

```
    while(!(PIR1bits.CCP1IF==1))   // this is missing a ;
        
     comtage= TMR1;                // this line gets executed in the loop
                                   // and adds instructions to the 
                                   // loop, this probably more than                     
                                   // halves the precision of your 
                                   // results.

                                   // the imprecision is increased with
                                   // your code that runs after the if block
```

Comment: it works very well, thanks a lot, I will try using interrupts, thanks again.